# Parse a string and cast certain elements to int

Tags: java, string, casting

I was working on a bit of code where you would take an input of 2 numbers, separated by a comma, and then would proceed to do other actions with the numbers.

I was wondering how I would parse the string to take the first number up to the comma, cast it to and int and then proceed to cast the second number to an int.

Here is the code I was working on:

```
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 2 numbers (num1,num2): ");

    //get input
    String input = Scan.nextLine();

    //parse string up to comma, then cast to an integer
    int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf(',')));

    int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(Scan.nextLine());
    Scan.close();

    System.out.println(firstNum + "\n" + secondNum);
```

The first number is cast to an integer just fine, I run into issues with the second one.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

How would I be able to then take the second integer out of the input string and cast it to an Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error mode you're encountering seems reasonable indeed, as you're reading the next line from the scanner and therefore explicitly no longer operating on the first input anymore.

What you're looking for is probably this:

```
int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.indexOf(',') + 1));
```

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense now, I need to re-access the original input and take every after the comma. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because all digit are given by the user on the same line. and you have two Scanner.nextLine(); the second is probably empty.

here is a solution :

```
Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter 2 numbers (num1,num2): ");

//get input
String input = Scan.nextLine();

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, ",");
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement()));
}

System.out.println(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining secondNum, you're setting it equal to the parsed integer of the next line the scanner object reads, but all of the data has already been read. So rather than read from the scanner again, you'll want to call Integer.parseInt on everything after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

If input on one line, both the numbers will be stored in the `String` variable `input`.   You don't need to scan another line.   It will be empty, and you cannot cast the empty string to an `int`.   Why not just parse the second number out of `input`, as you did the first.

Comment: Yeah, Dolda2000's answer let me know that and I was able to fix my code